# Transfer large data object via WCF client to WCF server

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to transfer a large data object from a WinForms client via WCF.

When the client tries to get the object from the server, the transfer succeeds; but
when the client tries to send the object to the server, I get an error!!

The error is:

> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel
>   channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

I try to add the behavior attribute `DataContractSerializer` and set it to max value. The transferring works only one way - from the server to the client! On the other side - from the client to the server it doesn't work!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you include the ErrorMessage for the exception?

Comment: Can you post the configuration you have on your client and server?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following parameters to your web.config file (adapt the value for your case):

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

...    

<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="512000000" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: according to msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.maxitemsinobjectgraph.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462(v=vs.90).aspx) `maxItemsInObjectGraph` is `System.Int32` and `maxAllowedContentLength` is `System.UInt32`

Answer (score 1):

There are several settings that control the max size of a message

- MaxBufferSize
- MaxReceivedMessageSize
- MaxStringContentLength

See: http://geekswithblogs.net/niemguy/archive/2007/12/11/wcf-maxstringcontentlength-maxbuffersize-and-maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx

Comment: This attributes are already included in the web config and its throw the same error

Comment: Have you included it on the server or the client side?